# SSIS update SQL task with problem ole db command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update, datediff

I have a table with 2 calculated column and I write a SQL command in OLE DB Command for update table

But it run with error

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FctRides]
   SET
       [trip finish]= case when [Finish] is null then [Expire] else [Finish] end
      ,[trip duration] = DATEDIFF("MI",[Start],(case when [Finish] is null then [Expire] else [Finish] end)) 
      ,[VendorId] =?
      ,[VehicleId] =?
      ,[RegionId] = ?
      ,[Status] = ?
      ,[Book] = ?
      ,[Start] = ?
      ,[Finish] = ?
      ,[Expire] =?
      ,[SourceId] = ?
      ,[DestinationId] = ?
      ,[Distance] = ?
      ,[Tariff] =?
      ,[Cost] = ?
      ,[Deleted] = ?
 WHERE [RideId]=?
```

The Output message is

```
Information: 0x40043009 at bicycle_fact_rides, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: bicycle_fact_rides
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\Shahram\source\repos\ssis bicycle\ssis bicycle\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Comment: What is the error? (Please [edit] into the question).

Comment: The supplied screenshot is helpful for showing what portion of the package has failed. However, go to the Output tab (lower right corner, currently shows Call Stack). Copy all the text that is in there, click Edit on your question and paste that in there.

Comment: thank's for your help. i add output error message into text

Comment: That's not _all_ of the content in the output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change My OLE DB Source and config again. the then problem solved
[Data flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y1gT.png)
[OLE DB Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS3vH.png)